# What's the difference between <b> and <strong>, <i> and <em> in html?

Tags: html

and now what tag i should use?

Answer (score 2):

According to the HTML 5 specification, the `<b>` tag should be used as a LAST resort when no other tag is more appropriate.

`<em>` refers to emphasized text

Important text should be denoted with the `<strong>` tag

`<i>` refers to italic text

The way to use all these tags are very depending on what you are trying to convey in your text/paragraph. Hope this helps!

Comment: Defaut what's tag should use? <b> or <strong>

Comment: @TháiSiuNhưn `<b>` should be used when you are only doing for styling. however, `<strong>` is used when you are trying to indicate something that should be understood. There's no visual difference between two tags but only difference comes with text-to-speech programs often used by blind people

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alvin

Comment: @TháiSiuNhưn No problem, if it helped you, just tick the tick. Always glad to help if I can.

Answer (score 0):

`<b>` - Bold text
`<strong>` - Important text
`<i>` - Italic text
`<em>` - Emphasized text

`<strong>` and `<em>` are used for important text. It means these texts are important.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nicehacker